# How do I solve Issue module 'tensorflow_core.contrib' has no attribute 'lite'?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I tried to convert my .h5 file to .tflite file using this code:

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('/drive/My Drive/FSD_modelV09A.h5')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("/drive/My Drive/FSD_modelV09A.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

but got this error instead:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.contrib' has no attribute 'lite'
```

I'm using Tensorflow version 1.15.0

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows but I also forgot to mention I'm using Google Colab to run this.

Comment: The TF Lite was moved from `tf.contrib.lite` to `tf.lite`